# Old Hamachi Server won't connect

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, hamachi

I have a 1.7.9 server that I decided to run again and it wont connect. To get the obvious things out of the way 
I have the Minecraft server window open,Hamachi is open and the server is on in Hamachi, I am in 1.7.9,
I have the correct IP typed in, it is allowed on the firewall
I haven't changed anything since the last time I used it (about 8 months) and would really appreciate if someone could help! Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

There is one thing you haven't specified: Are you unable to connect to your own server? Or are your friends unable to connect but you aren't? Or perhaps, your friends are but you cannot?

That missing information asside, I have some more questions:

Is the server actually generating a world, and the files associated? (assuming you have accepted the EULA (also assuming that 1.7.9 servers require you to. I can't remember when they added that))

What is the error message you get when you try and log on? Or is it simply telling you that it can't resolve the hostname?

---

If you like, I can log on and troubleshoot it for you. But don't trust shady people you meet on the internet.

---

My ***guess*** is that because Hamachi isn't the *best*, your friends (assuming your friends are the ones who cannot connect, and you can) do not have a direct connection to you and simply cannot reach the server. The solution to which, is simply to try and play during the middle of the day, when the internet around your area is not in as much use.

If *you* are the individual having trouble connecting to your own server, then the problem is most likely due to human error. Check your server properties. And remember that if the server port is anything other than '**25565**', you must type the port along with the IP address when you try and connect. E.X.: ":","0.0.0.0:12345".

Comment: Yes, I am not able to connect to my own server. The server port is '25565' and I have been trying to copy the properties to a new server. There is no EULA in 1.7.9

Comment: oh and the error message is: "Java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused:

Comment: The error basically says (surprise surprise) that your computer could not reach the server. This can be clientside or serverside. If its clientside, then either you are probably in offline mode (turn it off and on again), or minecraft is not allowed through your firewall (make sure you did the firewall correctly). If its serverside, it likely means the server was incorrectly port forwarded. Hamachi, however, does this automatically. I would recommend doing away with Hamachi, and port forwarding. Try connecting with "localhost" as the IP. May not work with Hamachi.

Comment: if I port forward the server will it be easier to recover my old server? Ive done everything and it doesnt work

Comment: My mistake for not mentioning: Port forwarding will not effect the files within your server. It will just change the IP on which the server runs. I suggest you google how to port forward based on your router. E.X.: "How to port forward on <myrouterhere>"